# Replace root node for Document

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I found a memory leak in my application using [libxml++](http://developer.gnome.org/libxml++/2.33/) due to an XML document where I replace the root node. I took good care for removing any child nodes, but using the `xmlpp::Document` interface I find no way to **replace** the root node.

This is a sample of the offending code:

```
xmlpp::Document Doc;
Doc.create_root_node("root");
// Populate the document
// [...]

void ReplaceRootNode(const xmlpp::Element* NewRootNode)
{
  // Remove all root node children
  xmlpp::Element* RootNode = Doc.get_root_node();
  const xmlpp::Node::NodeList Children = RootNode->get_children();
  xmlpp::Node::NodeList::const_iterator itChild = Children.begin();
  while (itChild != Children.end()) {
    RootNode->remove_child(*itChild++);
  }

  // Replace root node
  Doc.create_root_node_by_import(NewRootNode); // Leak: memory for previous root node is not freed
}
```

The solution I came up with so far is to edit the document's root node to change it's name and attributes but. Is there a simpler way to avoid this leak which does not involve edition of previous root node's name and attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I work around this by setting the document to an empty Document object (`Doc = xmlpp:Document()`) before calling `create_root_node_by_import` instead of removing the root's child nodes explicitly. This appears to cause the previous contents of `Doc` to be freed.

I first encountered this problem several years ago, and it still does not appear to be fixed in recent versions of libxml++. Surely they must be aware of it. Could this case somehow be using `create_root_node_by_import` in an unintended fashion? I would not have thought so, but OTOH this seems too important not to fix.

Comment: I suspected the same, that `create_root_node_by_import`'s usage was not intended in such a way, thus the question.